How should I split my dataset if I am applying oversampling?
Related: How can I apply multiple sampling tenchiques to a single dataset?
Suppose I have a dataset called my_dataset.dat with a length of 1079134 rows.
This dataset has three classes and has a class imbalance, as shown as follows:
LabelColumn
A    459325
C    377954
B    241855

I want to apply both random oversampling and SMOTE to this dataset.
However, how and when should I split the dataset into training-set, validation-set, and testing-set?
Option #1.

Split the dataset into training_set, validation_set, and testing_set
Apply oversampling to training_set only
Train the model using training_set
Validate the model using validation_set
Test the model using testing_set

Option #2.

Split the dataset into set_1 and validation_set
Apply oversampling to set_1
Split the set_1 into training_set and testing_set
Train the model using training_set
Validate the model using validation_set
Test the model using testing_set

Option #2 doesn't make any sense to me. However, this technique has been suggested in a Q1 impact factor 10 journal.
Note: Authoritative answer needed.

You probably shouldn’t oversample at all.

Option #1 is generally the preferred approach in dealing with imbalanced datasets and applying oversampling techniques. Here’s a breakdown of why Option #1 is the better choice and why Option #2 might have been suggested despite its potential drawbacks:
Option #1: Preferred Approach
Split the dataset into training_set, validation_set, and testing_set:
Ensures that the validation and testing sets represent the original class distribution and are not influenced by the oversampling process, providing a more realistic assessment of model performance.
Apply oversampling to training_set only:
Oversampling (either random oversampling or SMOTE) is applied only to the training set to mitigate the class imbalance without affecting the integrity of the validation and testing sets.
Train the model using training_set:
Use the oversampled training set to train the model, allowing the model to learn effectively from a balanced dataset.
Validate the model using validation_set:
Validate the model on the original, unaltered validation set to tune hyperparameters and avoid overfitting.
Test the model using testing_set:
Finally, evaluate the model on the original, unaltered testing set to measure its true performance.
Option #2: Alternative Approach
Split the dataset into set_1 and validation_set:
Initial split where the validation set is kept aside.
Apply oversampling to set_1:
Oversampling is applied to set_1, which might then introduce sampling bias in subsequent splits.
Split the set_1 into training_set and testing_set:
Further dividing set_1 into training and testing sets could result in an unrealistic testing set that does not represent the original data distribution.
Train the model using training_set:
Train the model on the oversampled training set.
Validate the model using validation_set:
Validate using the original validation set.
Test the model using testing_set:
Test using a potentially oversampled testing set, which does not reflect real-world scenarios.
Why Option #2 Might Have Been Suggested
Option #2 might have been suggested in certain scenarios where the primary concern is ensuring that the training and testing set benefit from the balancing process. However, it is generally less favored because:
Testing Set Bias: The testing set might not represent the real-world class distribution, leading to overestimating model performance.
Overfitting Risk: If the testing set is balanced through oversampling, the model might perform well on this synthetic distribution but poorly on real-world data.
Conclusion
Option #1 is typically the best practice because it ensures that the validation and testing sets remain faithful to the original data distribution, allowing for a realistic evaluation of the model’s performance. It helps avoid biases and overfitting, ensuring the results are generalizable to real-world data.

ChatGPT generated answer.
